# Bash change number to another value on specific line

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

i'm new with bash scripting , and i looking for solution to change a number to another value on specific line. 
I have file named **foo.config** and in this file i have about 100 lines of configuration. 
For example i have

`<UpdateInterval>2</UpdateInterval>`

and i need to find this line on **foo.config** and replace number(this can be number for 0 to 10 and for my example is 2) for 0 as always.

Like this : 
`<UpdateInterval>0</UpdateInterval>`

How can i do it with sed ? please suggest

the part of lines:

```
<InstallUrl />
<TargetCulture>en</TargetCulture>
<ApplicationVersion>1.0.1.8</ApplicationVersion>
<AutoIncrementApplicationRevision>true</AutoIncrementApplicationRevision>
<UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
<UpdateInterval>2</UpdateInterval>
<UpdateIntervalUnits>hours</UpdateIntervalUnits>
<ProductName>xxxxxxxxxxxx</ProductName>
<PublisherName />
<SupportUrl />
<FriendlyName>xxxxxxxxxxxx</FriendlyName>
<OfficeApplicationDescription />
<LoadBehavior>3</LoadBehavior>
```

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax .. and rest of the manual.. you'll get at least some idea to solve it

Comment: show more context (surrounding) lines

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sed* and others(*grep*, *awk*) never be a good tools for parsing xml/html data. Use a proper xml/html parsers, like **[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html)**:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -O -u "//UpdateInterval" -v 0 foo.config
```

- `ed` - edit mode
- `-L` - edit the file *inplace*
- `-O` - omit xml declaration
- `-u` - update action
- `"//UpdateInterval"` - xpath expression
- `-v 0` - the new value of the element to be updated

---

The final (exemplary) `foo.config` contents:

```
<root>
  <InstallUrl/>
  <TargetCulture>en</TargetCulture>
  <ApplicationVersion>1.0.1.8</ApplicationVersion>
  <AutoIncrementApplicationRevision>true</AutoIncrementApplicationRevision>
  <UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
  <UpdateInterval>0</UpdateInterval>
  <UpdateIntervalUnits>hours</UpdateIntervalUnits>
  <ProductName>xxxxxxxxxxxx</ProductName>
  <PublisherName/>
  <SupportUrl/>
  <FriendlyName>xxxxxxxxxxxx</FriendlyName>
  <OfficeApplicationDescription/>
  <LoadBehavior>3</LoadBehavior>
</root>
```

The `<root>` tag was specified for demonstration purpose, your xml/html structure should have its own "root"(most parent) tag

Answer (score 1):

In a very simple way, you may try:

```
sed -E 's/^<UpdateInterval>[0-9]+/<UpdateInterval>0/' foo.config
```

This will search for `<UpdateInterval>` at the beginning of a line (note the `^`) and then a number (`[0-9]` stands for a digit and `+` for a repetition of one or more). This bit will be replaced with `<UpdateInterval>0`. The `/` characters separate what you search and what will replace it. The `s` command is a search and replace.

It will take the file `foo.config` as input and you will get the output on standard output. If you want your output on the same file, you may do:

```
sed -E 's/^<UpdateInterval>[0-9]+/<UpdateInterval>0/' foo.config >foo.temp
mv foo.temp foo.config
```

Or more simply:

```
sed -i -E 's/^<UpdateInterval>[0-9]+/<UpdateInterval>0/' foo.config
```

Note that this is not a good way to do the substitution if your config file contains *general* XML. It will only work in the simplest of cases (but will do for your example.) If your XML bit may be in the middle of a line, remove the `^` character. The search and replace expression assumes that there is no whitespace around the XML tags.

Comment: You might want to use `sed -i` instead of writing to a temp file.

Comment: @glenn jackman, yes, thanks for the suggestion. I was trying to make it simple, but `sed -i 's/^<UpdateInterval>\d+/<UpdateInterval>0/' foo.config` will do the full work too.

Comment: sed doesn't support `\d`.. use `[0-9]` instead.. and you need `-E` option to use `+` like that

Comment: @Sundeep, I have tested before posting and it works with the `sed` I have. But you are right. It is better to use `-E` for portability. The `\d` I will fix. That is perl-ish...

Answer (score 0):

A solution using an XML parsing tool:

```
{ echo '<root>'; cat foo.config; echo '</root>'; } |
  xmlstarlet ed -O -P -u //UpdateInterval -v 0 |
  sed '1d;$d' |
  sponge foo.config
```

The first line is to make the config file into a proper XML file.
The second line updates the value.
The third line removes the root tags.
The last line rewrites the config file. Need to install the `moreutils` package.